# Images not working on sub directory install of WordPress network

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to install a Network of WordPress sites. The main site (which is in the root) already running since 2008. Everything fine except uploaded files. I have changed my uploads folder to `/assets/` since my main site started. All images working on main site but sub folder site's images not working. For example, the main site's image URL

`www.mysite.com/assets/2013/04/someimage.jpg`

which is working perfect. but the sub folder site's image path showing

`www.mysite.com/test/assets/sites/1/2013/04/someimage.jpg`

if I remove the sub site's name from URL (in this case it is 'test') it works. that means the image was uploaded to

`www.mysite.com/assests/sites/1/someimage.jpg (without sub folder site's name).`

and I can see the same through FTP. But WordPress rendering the URL with sub site's name. I think there should be some error on .htaccess redirect.

Below is the content of my .htaccess file:

`# BEGIN WordPress

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # uploaded files

    #RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin

    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]

    RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteRule . index.php [L]

    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress`

The site is hosted on Godaddy shared for testing. The live site will go on a dedicated server after all test.

Comment: You don't have `assets` or `sites` anywhere in the rewrite rules. How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

The real files are below `/assets/sites/`. To strip the site's name from the request, you must capture the latter part and rewrite to that

```
RewriteRule ^.*?/(assets/sites/.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

**Update**:

If the files are served by `wp-includes/ms-files.php`, it must be something like

```
RewriteRule ^.*?/(assets/sites/.*)$ wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I thought it will automatically done by wp-includes/ms-files.php, I'm not sure @Olaf Dietsche can you please change the whole code me?

Comment: @Kanu I'm not familiar with Wordpress and uploaded files. Please see updated answer, maybe it works.

Comment: Sorry, Above code not worked. WordPress still rendering with sub site's name in URL. Any one who familiar with network sites?